# datatables conflict with jquery Laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins, laravel-8

I am working on Laravel 8, using datatables and a package(maatwebsite/excel) for import/export data to database.

**My datatables have the below jQueries.**

```
<script src="{{ asset ('../assets/vendor_components/datatable/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset ('backend/js/pages/data-table.js') }}"></script>
```

These are loaded in the *admin.blade.php*

I have a view for export/import data called *learnerimport.blade.php*. Where i am loading the below jquery

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" defer integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

When i remove the jquery in my *admin.blade.php*, the import/export work perfectly in my *learnerimport.blade.php*. But the data-tables lose its functionalities.

Can anybody help me understand the problem. And also direct me towards having a solution?

Am new to coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "jquery" exactly? You might want to change that to script or jquery plugin embeds